# Как установить доп. библиотеки на убунту для построения ос андроид

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-sources

Я следовал стандартному ману на эту тему. Но некоторые библиотек не устанавливаются, пишется ошибка:

> E: Couldn't find package lib32readline5_dev
>
> E: Couldn't find package lib32ncurses5-dev

И так далее. Какой набор пакетов необходимо установить для построения сорцов андроида?

UPD: Как решается проблема:

> curl (6) Couldn't resolve host 'android.git.kernel.org'

Есть ли зеркало для исходников?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что выдаёт google:

- [How do I install the build dependencies for Android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25727/how-do-i-install-the-build-dependencies-for-android)
- [Android C native development – take full control!](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=682)

kernel.org сейчас недоступен. Зеркала мне неизвестны, можно скачать архивы с исходниками на [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=google+android&entity=project)

Comment: Не, конечно спасибо, но гуглом я пользоваться умею. Я надеялся на более развернутый ответ, с пояснениями.

Comment: Уточните, что неясно. Вопрос довольно широкий.